# ¿Cómo evito que se cierre un programa escrito en C en el cmd de Windows?

Tags: c, windows, cmd, printf

Cuando introduzco el valor, automáticamente se cierra la *CMD*. ¿Cómo hago para que no se cierre y dé tiempo a leer el segundo `printf`?

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
int a;

printf("Digite el valor de a: ");
scanf("%i", &a);
printf("La variable a vale: %i", a);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Usa un scan más al final. De esa forma, la ejecución espera que el usuario ingrese texto antes de terminar el programa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa la funcion:

`getchar()` -> [Aqui](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar)

Esta esperara hasta que se presione algun caracter.

Puedes tambien usar:

`sleep(int)`[Aqui](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep)

Esta esperar una cantidad de segundos antes de cerrar el programa.

**Windows**

Puedes hacer:

`system("pause")`

Este te dara el mensaje de

"Presione una tecla para continuar..."

Espero te sirva

Comment: Para complementar la respuesta para usar Sleep(x) tienes que usar la libreria Window.h y es usual usar el system("pause "); porque despues que ingresas el valor que es que esta detenida la ejecución imprime muy rapidamente el valor y cierra la consola

Comment: Supongo que tambien depende del SO, en caso GNU/Linux, se usa

Comment: #include <unistd.h>

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar simplemente `getch();` antes de la terminacion de tu programa

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
int a;

printf("Digite el valor de a: ");
scanf("%i", &a);
printf("La variable a vale: %i", a);

getch();

return 0;
}
```

`getch()` espera el ingreso de algun caracter mediante el teclado.